# How do I check whether the controls in a usercontrol contain any value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

How do I check whether the controls in a usercontrol contain any value?

I have created a usercontrol called ctlCustomerAddress and I want to create an address record in the database if only I have the values in the textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways to validate user input. You may use `Validation` Control (RequiredField), or write `JavaScript` code or write server side code to validate the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation controls. Also write the save to DB code to a button inside the user control rather then the parent page ?

Answer (score 0):

Is a `RequiredValidator` control what you're looking for?  [MSDN Reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You can also use `CustomerValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator` controls.

Set their `ValidationGroup` properties to be the same as your submit button.